# recursive function that finds the first error in the array

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to solve a problem which asks to return the subscript of the first element in the array for which the somePredicate function returns false.  If there is no such element, return -1.

Note that I need to use somePredicate for evaluating the correctness
of each element in the array and I cannot have any loops in my firstFalse function.

My function looks like this

```
int firstFalse(const string a[], int n)
```

where a[] is an array of strings and n is the number of elements in the array

and here is the somePredicate function

```
bool somePredicate(string s)
{

    int nDigits = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k != s.size(); k++)
    {
        if (isdigit(s[k]))
            nDigits++;
    }

    return nDigits == 5;
}
```

I am just learning how recursion works, and it is a nightmare, I spend 3 hours on this particular problem and no luck. Please someone explain the logic of how I need to precede here. I understand how recursion works to some degree but I cant figure out logically how to approach this problem.

Comment: Do you **need** recursion?  IMO, this is better solved iteratively.

Comment: Yes Thomas, I do need recursion since the whole point of this problem was to learn how to use recurison :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question implies that you have to use recursion. Ok, now try to break this down into logical steps.

1) You are to determine this for an array of size "n"

2) If the array is empty, that is, if n=0, the answer is obvious. You didn't find such element, so you return -1

3) If the array is not empty, recursively call your function for an array of size `n-1`.

4) Did your recursive call return an answer? Assume that the recursive call returns the correct answer for an array of size `n-1` That is, if it returned something other than -1, then you, in turn return the same answer for the array of size `n`.

5) Otherwise, if the recursive call returned -1, it must mean that for the array of size `n-1`, the predicate function returned true for all elements (or the array was empty). In this case, the answer is obvious: call the predicate function for element array[n-1] (the last element in an `n`-sized array that you're checking now). If it returns false, then the last element in the array of size `n` is the first such element that the predicate function returned false for, so you therefore return `n-1`, otherwise the return value is -1, since the predicate function is yet to return true.

Now, translate the above to code, and you will have your answer.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder if this topic is dificult for me only or for lots of people. After seeing an explanation, everything seems super easy, but upon stumbling on another example, I get stuck again.

Comment: Certainly some people have problems grasping the concepts involved in recursive thinking. I don't know if it's most people, or just some people; but I'm sure you're not the only one who has to come to grips with this kind of a mental viewpoint.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, after spending 3 hours on this stupid problem, I think I finally solved it, but that required hours of trial and error. Please someone explain how can i approach these type of problems to find the solution easier.

Here is my solution, and if someone can offer a better one, please let me know.

```
int firstFalse(const string a[], int n)
{
    if(n<0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    else
    {
        if(somePredicate(a[n])==false)
        {
            if(firstFalse(a,n-1)== -1)
                return n;
        }
        else
        {
            return firstFalse(a,n-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has an obvious bug. It has an execution path where the function exits without returning a value, leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, if n represents the number of elements in the array like you said, somePredicate(a[n]) won't work properly.

Comment: Sam are you talking about the path if somePredicate is false and inside
 ifirstFalse(a,n-1) is not -1 ? how can I fix this problem ?

Diego, im not sure if you are correct.

Jeremi P, you are right, n is actually the index of the last element, not the number of elements.

Comment: @user1335175 yeah, I'm not sure anymore either. I saw you were starting from the end of the array and going backwards and probably concluded wrongly that it was the last. anyway, I would go forward if I had to do it

Comment: Diego, the problem that I am facing with going forwad is that I am not sure how to stop the infinite recursion. Here I have an if n<0 return -1. What would you use if going from beginning to the end ?

Comment: the recursive call would use `a+1` and `n-1`, when `n==0` the array is empty. However, there is extra bookkepping to do to return the subscript